# What is wrong with this peach/apricot?

Tags: diagnosis, fruit-trees, plant-health

There's a young tree in my in-laws garden, I'm 90% sure it's a peach/apricot. As you can see in the pictures, it doesn't look healthy. Can someone point me to what may be wrong with it? A couple of notes, this is in eastern/central Europe, temperate climate, hardiness zone 6-7-ish. There's another peach tree in the same garden planted at the same time, it's already bearing fruit.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: I think it's an apricot tree, mostly because peach trees have a different leaf shape. Unfortunately I don't know what's wrong with it, but I hope somebody else has an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe that plant's root system is being deprived of the proper oxygen it needs.